# Ruby Net::HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: ruby, httpresponse, net-http

I'm trying to use http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/listed-companies/nordic-large-cap to scrape data of it. Here is my code to send a get request using Net::HTTP:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def get_stocks()
    uri = URI.parse('http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/listed-companies/stockholm')
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    puts response
 end

get_stocks()
```

Other sites I've tested works good and responds with a 200:OK but http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/listed-companies/nordic-large-cap returns a `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x00007ffe8f84ec30>` and I can't understand why.

For further context `response.body` returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="TEXT/HTML; CHARSET=utf-8"/>
<title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
    <H2>400 Bad Request</H2>
    <p>The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.</p>
    <p>This page can't be displayed.<br/>The incident ID is: 10039581164792379.</p>
    <p>If you would like assistance, please contact the Support for additional information.<br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to get a `200:OK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your need to set request's `User-Agent` property.
The following code works.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def get_stocks()
  uri = URI.parse("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/listed-companies/nordic-large-cap")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36'
  request.initialize_http_header({"User-Agent" => user_agent})

  response = http.request(request)
  puts response.inspect 
 end

get_stocks() # #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

You can get response body using `response.body`